# Idling resource exits even when isIdleNow() returns false in espresso

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have an idling resource which is supposed to tell espresso to wait for 140 seconds. the first time i run the test, it was working. but subsequent runs fails. that is, my test exist without waiting for 140 seconds even when `isIdleNow()` returns false. what could be the cause?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainTest {

  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule<Main> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(Main.class);

  private static Context getContext() {
    return InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
  }

  private static Context getTestContext() {
    return InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();
  }


  @Test
  public void waitForSomeSeconds() {
    long minutesInMills =  DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS;
    long waitTime = minutesInMills * 10;
    waitFor(waitTime);
  }



  private void waitFor(long waitingTime){

    IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(waitingTime * 14, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout((waitingTime * 14), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // Now we wait
    IdlingResource idlingResource = new ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(waitingTime*7);
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource);


      onView(withId(R.id.mInstructions))
              .perform(typeText("ok time up!"),closeSoftKeyboard());


    // Clean up
    Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource);
  }

  public void setMessage(String message){
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

**My idling resource**

```
    public class ElapsedTimeIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
  private final long startTime;
  private final long waitingTime;
  private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

  public ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(long waitingTime) {
    this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isIdleNow() {
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

    Log.d("Idling", " elasped time is " + elapsed + " waiting time is " + waitingTime);

    boolean idle = (elapsed >= waitingTime);
    Log.d("Idling", " idel is " + idle);
    if (idle) {
      resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
    }
    return idle;
  }

  @Override
  public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
    this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks strange that you are calling waitFor(waitTime) inside waitForSomeSeconds(), while the waitFor method has 2 parameters:  private void waitFor(long waitingTime, boolean success)

Comment: @VyacheslavPedak   i made the corrections. removed that boolean